# C# Structs, 16 byte rec. - Are getters and setters included in that?

Tags: c#, data-structures, byte

I was reading into the nitty-gritty of structs in C# here: ["C Fundamentals, The differences between struct and class."](https://web.archive.org/web/20200221090549/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/07/29/c-fundamentals-the-differences-between-struct-and-class.aspx)
and at the very bottom it mentions keeping a struct below 16 bytes. I looked elsewhere and saw that it is commonly recommended, though it sounds like it's been bumped up a bit to 20-24 bytes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082311/why-should-a-net-struct-be-less-than-16-bytes) in later versions of .NET.

My question is, are they just adding up the ints, doubles, etc. to total the 16 bytes, or are they talking about the size after compile, and if so, wouldn't getters and setters add to that?

Comment: I think that size recommendation is fairly soft. See for example [System.Numerics.Matrix4x4](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.matrix4x4?view=net-6.0) that is 64 bytes. And you can avoid the copy overhead by using references in many cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The size of a `struct` refers to the struct's *fields.*

Automatic Properties include a field as part of their compiled structure; this field counts towards the size of the `struct`.

Otherwise, properties are no different from functions - they are not part of the struct's instance at all, since there's nothing particular to *that* instance in the property.

Comment: Thanks. I had a feeling it was just the fields. :) I'm confused on the last paragraph though. Could you go into more detail on that. Are you saying that once it's on the stack that it's really just the fields and their data, literally just the structured data, that's there and that the getters and setters will end up elsewhere?

Comment: @BrianChandler - yes. Functions of a struct don't get duplicated on the stack endlessly.

Comment: @BrianChandler Methods (whether on structs or on classes) aren't specific to the instances they're called on. You can think of `myObject.myMethod(someArg)` as a call to a free function like `myClass_myMethod(myObject, someArg`. That free function takes the receiver (the object it's called on) as an argument, but it doesn't need to be stored *in* that object. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodbase.invoke?view=net-6.0#system-reflection-methodbase-invoke(system-object-system-object()) for example